# Jquery ajax call not working in Firefox when no delay in loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

Here is the code:

```
    function onSelectClient(index) {

        var orderNumber = "123";

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "myAspx.aspx/GetPASR",
            data: '{orderNumber: "' + orderNumber + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
        alert("After Call");
        return false;
    }

function OnSuccess(response) {
       //Do some stuff and then below

        location = "myAspx.aspx";
    }
```

The ajax call works good in IE and chrome.
In Firefox, it works when I have that alert after the call and I take a second to click on "Ok".
It does not work in firefox (V 36.0.1) when I don't have that alert or if I keep my mouse ready at the right place and click on Ok right when it appears.
Also, I see two errors in the console in FF.
1. "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead." - I see this in all pages of the application which are working good. So, this is not likely to cause the trouble.
2. "uncaught exception: out of memory". Not sure if it is related.

Answer (score 4):

Is making it a synchronous call an option? I had the same problem and got it working with async:false.

Comment: Tried all other solutions. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: `AJAX = AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML`. Whats the point of having AJAX with `async: false` if your function needs to wait for completion of the call before it can execute next statement. I can't think of a reason why this option is even needed!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR;**

I have been reading a lot of questions on `uncaught exception: out of memory` lately. I think the problem is more with the HTML code of the form submission button than the ajax call (which appears fine to me). Well, at least this answer is based on a pure assumption that you are using button `type="submit"` to post your data.

When using ajax, it is best to use button type `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`. The latter creates a problem in firefox(which is logically reasonable, keep reading to know why). Though, you didn't mention anything about page reloading, but I'm guessing the page was reloading when it worked on FF(with an `alert()`).

My reasoning for `uncaught exception: out of memory` is that when you are submitting your form(believing that it is an ajax call), the form is actually being submitted by the submit button at the same time when ajax is supposed to handle the request, leading to parallel `POST` requests. This also explains why your form submission was working with a delay in ajax due to the 'alert()' - the requests didn't go parallel.

About the other message `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated`, I believe it is a warning and not an error. This will hardly affect your functions as long as you jquery is not updated which doesn't support `getPreventDefault()`. BTW, if you look inside your `jQuery.js`, you will find a line like `this.isDefaultPrevented=e.defaultPrevented||e.getPreventDefault&&e.getPreventDefault()?U:Y` which may be causing this warning. If you want to get rid of this warning, change the line to `this.isDefaultPrevented=e.defaultPrevented?U:Y`. Also, look for more occurrences of `getPreventDefault` and change as required. **NOTE:** do not edit the library if you are not sure of the changes you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax worked in my case on Firefox. Though I have made it `async: false` since I have to wait for first call to be finished then second call shall start.

```
$.ajax({
   url : url,
   async : false,
   type: post,
   dataType : html,
   data : data,
   success : xxx,
   error : yy
});
```